# How do I change the font of colorbar to latex?

Tags: matlab, latex, figure, colorbar

I have a MATLAB figure with a colorbar. I am trying to change the font of the ticks of the colorbar to LateX. I've tried this,

```
hBar = colorbar;set(hBar, 'FontName', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

But MATLAB gives this error,

"Error using matlab.graphics.illustration.ColorBar/set
Invalid parameter/value pair arguments."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the interpreter for the tick labels to LaTeX, you have to set the [`TickLabelInterpreter` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html#bt6akfm_sep_shared-TickLabelInterpreter) of the [colorbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html):

```
hBar = colorbar;
set(hBar, 'TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex');

% Or...

colorbar('TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex');
```

Also note this excerpt from the documentation in relation to the font:

> The displayed text uses the default LaTeX font style. The `FontName`, `FontWeight`, and `FontAngle` properties do not have an effect. To change the font style, use LaTeX markup within the text.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the font name, but then not providing a valid font.

```
hBar = colorbar;
set(hBar, 'FontName', 'times new roman');
```